# How to get all attributes for a particular xml node in qt

Tags: python, xml, qt, pyqt

is it possible to get all attributes for a particular node in pyqt ?
for example .. consider for following node:

`< asset Name="3dAsset" ID="5"/>`


i want to retrieve the ("Name" and "ID") strings
is it possible?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can retrieve the particular value of the attribute using the function,

```
QString QDomElement::attribute ( const QString & name, const QString & defValue = QString() ) const
```

To get all the attributes use,

```
QDomNamedNodeMap QDomElement::attributes () const
```

and you have to traverse through the DomNamedNodeMap and get the value of each of the attributes. Hope it helps.

**Edit** : Try this one.

With the QDomNamedNodeMap you are having give,

```
QDomNode QDomNamedNodeMap::item ( int index ) const
```

which will return a QDomNode for the particular attribute.
Then give,

```
QDomAttr QDomNode::toAttr () const
```

With the QDomAttr obtained give,

```
QString name () const
```

which will return the name of the attribute.
Hope it helps.

Comment: it returns a DomNamedNodeMap  and i couldn't see how it can help me with retrieving the strings ( "Name" ) and ("ID") , i don't want the values of those attributes. i just want the attribute name .

Answer (score 2):

How to get first attribute name/value in PySide/PyQt:

```
if node.hasAttributes():
    nodeAttributes = node.attributes()
    attributeItem = nodeAttributes.item(0) #pulls out first item
    attribute = attributeItem.toAttr()
    attributeName = attr.name()
    attributeValue = attr.value()
```

This just shows how to get one name/value pair, but it should be easy enough to extend looping with `nodeAttributes.length()` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is for c++. I Ran into the same problem. You need to convert to QDomAttr. I'm sure API is the same in python.

```
if( Node.hasAttributes() )
{
    QDomNamedNodeMap map = Node.attributes();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < map.length() ; ++i )
    {
        if(!(map.item(i).isNull()))
        {
            QDomNode debug = map.item(i);
            QDomAttr attr = debug.toAttr();
            if(!attr.isNull())
            {
                cout << attr.value().toStdString();
                cout << attr.name().toStdString();
            }
    }
}
```